# Local Auth Saving Refresh Token to collection, but Mongoose throwing session validation error with Google OAuth (using Passport) for field 'username'

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, passport.js

I am running into a bit of a peculiar issue. I have set up both local and OAuth2.0 via Google using Passport. Both implementations are using the same sign in middleware to create refresh and access tokens for JWT authentication.

The issue I am running into is that when I use Google OAuth strategy and populate the "userTokenObj" (same fields as local and used to create both refresh and access JWTs, as well as save refresh/session information to Mongo Atlas for persistent login) and save that information to the db, Mongoose is throwing the following error: `Session validation failed: username: Path` username `is required. error caught in signin middleware!`.

I have tried to follow to the thread of execution, logging each middleware as they are invoked and have logged the userTokenObj before it is used to save session/refresh information to the db and everything works as expected, yet Mongoose still claims that the 'username' field is not populated even though it shows up in the console.

Below is the code for the Google OAuth route, passport config with Google Strategy, and signin controller:

```
    router.get(
  '/google/callback',
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    passport.authenticate(
      'google',
      { session: false },
      (err: any, userTokenObj: Payload) => {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          return next(err);
        }
        if (!userTokenObj) {
          // Handle authentication failure - return error in next
          return next();
          res
            .status(401)
            .json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed' });
        }
        console.log(
          '#2 auth google callback - userToken obj set on res locals',
          userTokenObj
        );
        // // Handle successful authentication
        res.locals.user = userTokenObj;
        return next();
      }
    )(req, res, next);
  },
  signin,
  (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log('inside of last middleware after signin - google route');
    res.status(200).json({ accessToken: res.locals.accessToken });
  }
);

import { Request } from 'express';
import passport, { DoneCallback } from 'passport';
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth2';
import db from '../models/model';
import { Payload } from '../types/jwtPayload';

const configureGoogleStrategy = () => {
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      async (
        request: Request,
        accessToken: string,
        refreshToken: string,
        profile: any,
        done: DoneCallback
      ) => {
        let userTokenObj: Payload;

        const queryString = 'SELECT email, id FROM users WHERE google_id = $1';
        const values = [profile.id];

        const user = await db.query(queryString, values);
        let providerData = profile._json;
        providerData.accessToken = accessToken;
        providerData.refreshToken = refreshToken;

        if (!user.rows.length) {
          const emailqueryString =
            'SELECT email, id FROM users WHERE email = $1';
          const emailvalues = [profile.email];
          const emailUser = await db.query(emailqueryString, emailvalues);

          if (emailUser.rows.length > 0 && !emailUser.rows[0].google_id) {
            const newqueryString =
              'UPDATE users SET google_id = $1 WHERE email = $2';
            const newValues = [profile.id, profile.email];
            await db.query(newqueryString, newValues);
            // const newemailuser = await db.query(emailqueryString, emailvalues);

            userTokenObj = {
              id: emailUser.rows[0].id,
              username: emailUser.rows[0].email,
            };
          } else {
            const newqueryString =
              'INSERT INTO users (email, google_id) VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING email, id';
            const newValues = [profile.email, profile.id];
            const newUser = await db.query(newqueryString, newValues);
            userTokenObj = {
              id: newUser.rows[0].id,
              username: newUser.rows[0].email,
            };
          }
        } else {
          userTokenObj = {
            id: user.rows[0].id,
            username: user.rows[0].email,
          };
        }
        console.log(
          '#1 - google auth strategy callback - userTokeObj passed to done, which gets passed to auth callback'
        );
        done(null, userTokenObj);
      }
    )
  );
};

export default configureGoogleStrategy;

export const signin = async (
  req: RequestUserObj | Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    // Determine if this is OAuth or local request

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    let userTokenObj = res.locals.user as Payload;

    if (email && password) {
      const text = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1';
      const value = [email];

      const user = (await db.query(text, value)).rows[0];

      if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
        userTokenObj = { id: user.id, username: user.email };
      } else {
        return next({
          log: 'Invalid email or password',
          message: 'Invalid email or password',
          status: 400,
        });
      }
    }

    if (!userTokenObj && (!email || !password)) {
      return next({
        log: `Request body missing email or password, req.body: ${req.body}`,
        message: 'Missing email or password',
        status: 400,
      });
    }

    const { id, username } = userTokenObj;

    const access = jwtService.generateAccessToken(userTokenObj);
    const refresh = jwtService.generateRefreshToken(userTokenObj);

    const { refreshToken } = await session.create({
      sql_id: id,
      username: email,
      refreshToken: refresh,
    });

    console.log(refreshToken);

    res.cookie('ssid', refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });

    res.locals.user = { accessToken: access, username };

    return next();
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return next({
      log: 'error caught in signin middleware!',
      status: 400,
      message: { err },
    });
  }
};
```